# Ionic app Run time error - Didn't find class com.vladstirbu.cordova.plugin.utils.AssetProvider

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework

I am getting the following error when I try to run an ionic android application.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.vladstirbu.cordova.plugin.utils.AssetProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.vladstirbu.cordova.plugin.utils.AssetProvider"
```

The app has been builded successfully and no error when installing it. But it is crashing when I try to open the app.
Can anyone please help me to solve the issue here?

Comment: post your package.json for more informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an issue with the recent 0.5.6 release of InstagramPlugin !

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-instagram-plugin
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-instagram-plugin@0.5.5
ionic cordova run android
```

I compiled with 0.5.5 and did not encounter this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here!

- ionic 3.20.0
- cordova 8.0.0
- OS: Mac OS X 10.13.4

Comment: These kind of remarks are not suitable as answers and should instead be posted as a comment ;)

Comment: Sorry! I haven't 50 reputation... :(

Comment: Whoops, forgot that that's an issue. No clue what the right way of handeling this is, sorry.